# How to mock the value of a property in Node/Express using Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to jest. I have a function where I validate the length of a property. If the length is exceeded, then the function returns the response with the `400` status code.

Config.js

```
module.exports = {
    maxLength: 50
}
```

Controller.js

```
const {
    maxLength
} = require("../config")

const sendMessage = (req, res) => {
        const {
            message
        } = req.body
        if (message.length > maxLength) {
            {
                res.status(400).send()
            }
}
```

I want to mock the value of `maxLength` to `2` when I write the unit tase. So that I can check without passing too many messages.

I have tried the following.

Controller.test.js

```
const config = require("../config")

confif.maxLimit=jest.fn()

describe('Cntroller.sendMessage', () => {
            it("should return 400 if the message length exceed", async () => {
                config.maxLength = 2;
                req.body = {
                    message: "hello I am new message"
                }
                await sendMessage(req, res)
                expect(res.statusCode).toBe(400)
            )
)
```

Here I have tried to mock the value of `maxLength` to `2` and the message length is 23. So the response status code will be 400. But the test has failed.

`Expected(400)`

`Recieved(200)`

How to mock the value of `maxLength`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will mock the `maxLength` to different value:

```js
jest.mock("../config", () => ({
  maxLength: 2
}))
```

As the `maxLength` is not a function I am not sure how could you change the mocked value to have different value for different test.